# Create a custom Lemma or Stem Dictionary for the Fulltext search in RDBMS: MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDb

Tags: mysql, postgresql, dictionary, stemming, lemmatization

I have my own non English dictionary with words in CSV format where every line represents a word. A single line starts with the word's base form followed by all its inflected forms.

I would like to use that file to create my own dictionary that sould be  used by the FULLTEXT search.

I prefer to use MySQL with that FULLTEXT search but if it is not possible to use MySQL with a custom dictionary then I can switch my project to PostgreSQL or MariaDB.

How to make MySQL or other RDBMS use custom dictionary for FULLTEXT search?
It would be nice to have a solution that works also with SQLite so it could be deployed to mobile apps as well.

So far I found related links that unlucky don't say how to do that:

[MySQL Stemming for full-text](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2423)  Status: Un-Assigned

[PostgreSQL Dictionaries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html)

If using a Lemma dictionary for FULLTEXT search is not possible with any of these RDBMS I think It should be possible to create at least a Stemming dictionary for the PostgreSQL as its extension but I haven't done any extension for PostgreSQL and don't know where to start especially in the context of creating your own dictionary for the FULLTEXT search.

Comment: You can use hunspell dictionaries in Postgres: https://github.com/postgrespro/hunspell_dicts - I think the .affix files are those that are needed to support stemming. To enable them, you don't really need to build an extension. After copying the files into the correct directories, you only need to run `create dictionary` as far as I know. This might be helpful as well: https://github.com/EvanCarroll/pg_hunspell/

Answer (score 0):

If you curently use MySQL then you could use the `ngram` plugin as specified in [ngram Full-Text Parser](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html) (you may also want to see [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/04/how-to-work-with-google-n-gram-data-sets-in-r-using-mysql/) article also).

Regarding the PostgreSQL link that you provided I don't think that you actually have any questions on that, it is straight forward how to configure it.